# Backbone router: Use hashbangs

Tags: backbone.js, router

I was setting up a simple router in Backbone.js while I noted an issue, I googled for a long time and found some solutions.

The problem is that whenever I navigate to a url, this url will work while I'm inside the app itself, but once you bookmark it and return it will obviously return a 404 since that page doesn't exist.

```
Backbone.history.navigate('test', true);
```

This will navigate to `http://www.domain.com/test`, which is great, but once you refresh the same URL it returns a 404.

There are ways to get this to work with using a specific `.htaccess` file, but I'm building this inside an existing website, so I can't use this.

Is there a way in Backbone.js to revert to just using hashbangs? My url would then look like this `http://www.domain.com/#!/test
This might not be the cleanest URL, but at least it will work.

Or am I just missing something obvious here? It can't be that I'm the only person with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `pushState` according to your url, so you've got 2 main options:

- stop using `pushState` when starting Backbone history (which would be the equivalent of using a hashbang, except for SEO)
- have your server return a page for every URL your app generates (it can be the same exact page)

In the second case, if you don't care about SEO, you can have a catch all rule always returning (e.g.) `index.html` containing your Backbone app. When you start Backbone's history, it will lokk at the URL and navigate to the proper page (although you might have a "double render" effect).

If you're worried about SEO, you need to return page content for SEO along with your Backbone app.

Comment: A third, more complex, option would be to render the Backbone app on the server using PhantomJS and send that to the client

Comment: I'm not really worried about SEO, I'm actually serving a static site with all data and scraping that using backbone. The thing I'm worried more about is that visitors can't bookmark URLs.
By removing `pushState` it uses hashes instead, which is exactly what I want!

Comment: @Bojangles Good suggestion, but sadly my site doesn't allow me to do that